# Winform browser shows script errors but IE doesn't

Tags: javascript, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am using Winform Broswer control inside WPF application the code snippet for the same is as below:

```
private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)  
{
   var host = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
   host.Child = webTest;
   this.SampleGrid.Children.Add(host);
   webTest.Navigate("https://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/cardiovascular-disorders/symptoms-of-cardiovascular-disorders/limb-pain?media=print");
}
```

Here if I use any other link such as
http://www.google.com it works fine.

But this link https://www.merckmanuals.com/professional/cardiovascular-disorders/symptoms-of-cardiovascular-disorders/limb-pain?media=print
gives javascript error when I tried to display it in Browser control.

The same link works fine when I use IE.

As per my knowledge the WebBrowser control uses dlls from IE so something that can be opened using IE can be opened using WebBrowser control as well.

I tried by using

```
webTest.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
```

But that just shows blank page without any script error.

I even tried by using WPF webbrowser control but no luck :(

Can somebody suggest what solution on this problem?

Answer (score 1):

it may be coused by wrong version of IE engine used by browser control.

Try to set correct Registry Key for your application maybe newer version of IE will handle that. As default WebBrowser control uses IE 7.0 engine.

Here is a long description how to achive that:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/may/21/web-browser-control-specifying-the-ie-version

Hope it hepls